# Change AWS ECS service's security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I would like to be able to modify the network configuration of an AWS ECS service.  The interface has "Allowed VPC", "Allowed subnets", "Security Groups", and "Auto-assign public IP" at the top of the "Configure network" screen.  However they cannot be modified.  We have been using a common security group for some of the services.  When creating one of the services we missed assigning the security group so a new one was created.  This seems like something I should be able to go back and correct.

Comment: You can try to edit the SG on the EC2 machines directly.

Comment: We are using Fargate so I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task_fargate.html), You can not change the security group of the fargate type ECS task, as the security group attach with [manages resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html). Like in case of ECS EC2 type task where you manage instances for the ECS so you can change the security group for the resources, go to EC2 instance -> modify resources -> modify SG but here is the case is different you do not have to manage as AWS belief container as services (cas).

Workaround:

- Go to security group -> select associated fargate SG -> modify the rule
- Launch another new fargate task and associate the desired SG for the fargate service.

[image]

Comment: This answer is correct as it applies to the AWS Management Console, however TheCodeMonk's solution below successfully addresses the issue using a CLI approach.

Answer (score 56):

You can change it if you use the AWS CLI.

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster ClusterName --service ServiceName --network-configuration file://c:\json\networkConfig.txt
```

Where your networkConfig.txt file contains

```
{
  "awsvpcConfiguration": {
    "subnets": ["subnet-***","subnet-***"],
    "securityGroups": ["sg-***"],
    "assignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct solution. I tested and can confirm. While it might be clear to advanced users, it's worth adding: you can add multiple security groups to the service using this format.

Comment: +1 This helped me as well. This command will work regardless of OS and doesn't need a file: `aws ecs update-service --cluster <cluster-name> --service <service-name> --network-configuration '{"awsvpcConfiguration": {"subnets": ["subnet-abcd","subnet-efgh","subnet-wxyz"], "securityGroups": ["sg-blabla"],"assignPublicIp": "ENABLED"}}'`

Comment: Note that this will not work if you are using AWS CodeDeploy as a deployment controller. (Blue/Green deploys powered by CodeDeploy)

You will see

`An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: Unable to update network parameters on services with a CODE_DEPLOY deployment controller. Use AWS CodeDeploy to trigger a new deployment.`

Comment: @NavidKhan I found out if you want to do this in CodeDeploy you need to add the networkconfiguration part to the Appspec file when you create a new deploy. It will then update the service during the deploy task.

Answer (score 0):

You can change security group settings with console:

1. Update service and select awsvpc version of template (typically latest). If you select different template version you will not see networking step
2. Follow service update wizard to select network and security groups

Comment: doesn't seem to work, it _shows_ the network configuration but doesn't give me an option to change it

Comment: can't find "awsvpc version of template" when updating service

Comment: A simple update won't do - You need to recreate the service using an updated awsvpc template. Maybe after the first edit it will show up on the second try...